# Generate SoapFault without throwing an exception

Tags: soap, asmx

I know that when there is an unhandled `Exception` in asmx that it generates a soapFault and returns it to the client. What I want to know is if there is a way to return a soapFault without throwing an exception. Throwing an exception is an expensive operation and I would like to avoid it if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such option (short from building the complete XML/SOAP message yourself that is)... with WCF this could be slightly easier IMO

You can throw a [`SoapException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and can customize it rather thoroughly:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833379/en-us
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480514.aspx

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but I'm not seeing anything that says it's possible either. Unfortunately in my case, it's an existing asmx service, and it is out of scope of the work to convert it to a WCF service.